# What is "We’ve detected that your app is using an old version of the Google Play developer API" warning in Google Developer Console?

Tags: android, google-api-java-client, google-developers-console

We do not use any Google Play Developer APIs explicitly, yet we are receiving the following warning:

[image]

Is this related to https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_releases_notes ?

We are currently using **Google Play Billing Library 1.2.2 Release (2019-03-07)**

We don't plan to migrate **Google Play Billing Library 2.0.1 Release (2019-06-06)** because it would be a lot of work with little gain.

> Purchases must be acknowledged within three days

But that is just my wild guess - that the Google Play Billing library is related to the Google Play Developer API. They may or may not be related to each other.

What does it mean by "We’ve detected that your app is using an old version of the Google Play developer API" ?

The following is the full set of our dependencies. Any idea what causes this warning?

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])


    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.2.2'


    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'


    def lifecycle_version = '2.0.0-beta01'
    // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"


    // alternately - if using Java8, use the following instead of compiler
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"


    def room_version = '2.1.0'
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    def work_version = "2.1.0"
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:$work_version"

    // https://github.com/yccheok/SmoothProgressBar
    implementation 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:1.1.0'

    // For Google Drive REST API - https://github.com/gsuitedevs/android-samples/blob/master/drive/deprecation/app/build.gradle
    implementation('com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.26.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.26.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    implementation('com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev136-1.25.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07'

    implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

    implementation 'com.github.yccheok:AndroidDraw:0.18'
    implementation 'com.github.yccheok:SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter:0.4'
    implementation 'com.github.yccheok:CalendarView:1.10'

    implementation 'com.andrognito.patternlockview:patternlockview:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'

    implementation 'com.github.yccheok:PhotoView:0.1'

    implementation 'com.github.yccheok:Matisse:1.6'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.1.1'

    // https://github.com/romandanylyk/PageIndicatorView
    implementation 'com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.2@aar'

    implementation 'me.zhanghai.android.materialratingbar:library:1.3.2'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:4.2.1"
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.23.0'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-core:2.0.0-RC.4'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:2.0.0-RC.4'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.0-RC.4'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0-alpha01'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0-alpha01'
}
```

For project level dependencies, it is

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Comment: `Google Play Billing library might be related to Google Play Developer API`
I think you're right

Comment: which library are you using at the backend to validate the purchases?

Comment: Looks like your **Google Drive** related libraries are using API that's deprecated. Visit this page : https://github.com/gsuitedevs/android-samples/tree/master/drive/deprecation

Comment: @JeelVankhede `com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev136-1.25.0`
He is already using v3 Drive API, and error specifically mentioned **Developer API**

Answer (score 22):

The problem is that your project **on Google Cloud Platform** is using an old version of Developer Web API. It was automatically set up for you when you enabled developer services intentionally/unintentionally from Google Play Console's **API Access** section in Developer Settings.

Web API for subscriptions and purchases is actually part of Android Developer API:

> The Google Play Developer API allows you to perform a number of publishing and **app-management tasks**. It includes two components:
>
> The Subscriptions and In-App Purchases API lets you manage in-app purchases and subscriptions.
> The Publishing API lets you upload and publish apps, and perform other publishing-related tasks.

You are **not using** above API in your app, this API is for management not the actual purchases. You are using SDK which has different versioning so no need to upgrade. This API was set up in your GCP project however.

To find which Project on GCP is associated with your Play Console, go to this link:
https://play.google.com/apps/publish/#ApiAccessPlace

[image]

**You just need to Go to GCP, find your project, find Google Android Developer API and change the version there. Or you can just disable the API if you don't use it.**

For example, my GCP project was automatically named **Google Play Android Developer** so yours might probably be the same.

I can't see an option on my console probably because they removed it for new projects, but if your project is already using an old version, you probably will have a warning there as well.

[image]

Comment: Could you explain a bit how to change the version after finding the API?

Comment: @MaximeTremblay-Savard **if there is no option to migrate**, then unlink from play store, delete project on google cloud and link it again to anew project.

Comment: What happens when the project is unlinked? Why is the project there in the first place?

Comment: @Manuel you won't be able to use those two APIs if you unlink project, if you are not using them already, it won't make a difference.
Basically you have to create a GCP project and then link it to your console project to use those two APIs

Comment: Thanks I was wondering why the project exists in the first place, but I discovered that it is the fastlane integration.

Answer (score 16):

> Any one have idea, what does it mean by "**We’ve detected that your app
>   is using an old version of the Google Play developer API**" ?

The simple explanation for this message is that: An app either yours or a third party app is hitting the `below api`

```
https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v1/applications
```

or

```
https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications
```

passing your app's package name along

```
com.android.myapp
```

in other to perform automated tasks like

```
Retrieve billing Info
Publish app to store
Retrieve review comments
etc..
```

Nevertheless those apis are deprecated an they're meant to go through the below api instead

```
https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications
```

Some third-party plugins have been confirmed to trigger this message, simply because they are using deprecated apis to perform their actions.

For example:

- [Fastlane for android](https://fastlane.tools/)  --See [discussion](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/14573)
- [Visual Studio IDE](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/) Distribution Channel for android apps with Xamarin.Forms  --See [discussion](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6528#issuecomment-510046846)
- [Jamesmontemagno Billing Library](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin) for Xamarin and Windows --See [discussion](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin/issues/221#issuecomment-486491407)

There is also a possibility that you are the one referencing the deprecated api maybe from your server side or "`just maybe`" in your own app code. The bottom line is that `a call somewhere is hitting a deprecated api` with your app's `package name`. An advice from me to you would be: `Update your billing library if you use one`.

Wrapping this up with the statement from [Google Developer API v3 doc](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/03/changes-to-google-play-developer-api.html)

> Usage of the API can also be indirect, not by the app itself, but by a
>   third-party plugin (e.g. a plugin for rolling out new releases). Many
>   third-party plugins are already using version 3 of the API. If you use
>   a plugin that does not support version 3, you will need to contact the
>   maintainer.

Comment: I have same problem as OP and I only use google support libraries as dependencies (nothing else, no 3rd party libs or jars). Also I dont use any API nor API keys, no remote servers communication, no in-app payment, and my app works offline so no internet access. And I still got warning, why? I dont think thats possible, it must be false warning

Comment: I can validate that it is not my plugin library at all for In App Billing. This is usually due to receipt validation servers or other extensions using older APIs.

Comment: I guarantee neither my app nor any other using my app's name is hitting this API.  So not only does this answer not even _suggest_ a solution _(meaning it shouldn't be an answer)_, it's not even correct.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't related to billing since you don't have server side validation. It's the [AndroidPublisher API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started) as other have mentioned, which means you probably have a pretty nasty security flaw. So, how to go about finding it?

1. Go to https://play.google.com/apps/publish/#AdminPlace
2. In there, you'll see a list of "Users with access." Some will be real, others will be Service Accounts. The latter end in `@gcp-project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com`
3. If there's anything you don't recognize, remove the account
4. If you want to further clean things up, go to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=**gcp-project-id** with the `gcp-project-id` from above

   1. *Don't* remove random service accounts here, most are auto generated from various other Google service and things will break if they disappear. *Do* remove the service accounts that had access to the Play Console if they aren't used to access other APIs.

Comment: I don't have a "Users with access" section.Do I have to do anything?

Answer (score 1):

Google Play Developer API is not directly used inside your app (APK), so you cannot fix it in **build.gradle**. It contains some services to help you automate app publishing (Continuous integration, CI) and also an API to validate in-app purchases.

You should check how your backend is validating in-app purchases and update to the latest version. You may also check how your CI server is uploading the APK to the Play Store and also update to the latest version.

You can read more about Google Play Developer API here https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/

Comment: We do have have any backend to validate in-app purchase. We also do not have any CI server.

Answer (score 0):

According to google documentation, you cannot use Google play developer version 1 and 2 as in documentation, they have mentioned that they are migrating to Version 3 and **In-app billing** is directly linked to this. 

Check first link to read it

1. https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/03/changes-to-google-play-developer-api.html

**To know about *Google Play Developer API***

Check https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/

For implementing Version 3

1. https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-publisher-api/tree/master/v3/java

2. https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/androidpublisher/v3

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Well yes, the OP seems to know that and claims to not directly use the SDK. The question was: how do you find out what is causing this notice then

Comment: There is no easy way to find what's causing it, the blog clearly says that the warning can also exist because "Usage of the API can also be indirect, not by the app itself, but by a third-party plugin". Apparently, the OP is using lots of libraries. "The message is based on all calls to the API in the last seven days and is refreshed daily".