# What is causing this warning in Google Play developer console: "We’ve detected that your app is using an old version of the Google Play developer API"

Tags: android, google-play, google-developers-console

**So my app is for free, does not use inapp billing, does not use any Google Dev API whatsoever.** I still got warning like this:

[image]

These are all dependences I use:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

Its including all libraries projects I use, all together, there is nothing else only this. Which one of them can cause this warning? Or is it false positive?

And these are permissions my app uses:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
```

**I do not use internet access, no API key, no developer API, no remote server communication, no online communication whatsoever, no in-app billing.**

Comment: Are you use place searching or location service ?

Comment: Needs to migrate AndroidX. Could be the reason

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya no location services, nothing

Comment: @MD that would make sense. But do you have any arguments for your claims? Because it basically means AndroidX will be mandatory soon....

Comment: @qkx Have you used anything in your project that really required API key ? I think AndroidX is not valid reason for this

Comment: nothing at all. I dont even use internet access. My app just reads events from calendar and displays them in widget, thats all.

Comment: @qkx, check the second answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56700332/what-is-we-ve-detected-that-your-app-is-using-an-old-version-of-the-google-play

Comment: Have you any old version in artifact which use google services ?

Comment: Did you check if `implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'` uses any Play Developers API?

Comment: @RakeshKumar I dont think link you posted is relevant to me. Second answer mentions checking inapp billing (which I do not use) or automated publishing (which I do not use)

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya please see my dependences again. You can see there that I DO NOT USE any google services, internet access, nothing at all

Comment: @ReazMurshed no I didnt because all libs I use are official from google. I might check it thought one by one, thanks for tip

Comment: @qkx, There in Google play console>API access> any project linked?

Comment: @RakeshKumar no, I dont use any API. My app is simple, offline app.

Comment: try updating support library to v4 instead of v13 here `com.android.support:support-v13`

Comment: can you show libs folder of project ?