# "We've detected this app uses an unsupported version of Play billing" for Xamarin Forms Android App

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

When attempting to publish my Xamarin Forms app, I get the following error from Google Play console

> We've detected this app uses an unsupported version of Play billing. Please upgrade to Billing Library version 3 or newer to publish this app.

I don't use any billing library. I've tried updating all nuget dependencies, to no luck.  How do I fix this error so I can publish my app?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56700332/what-is-we-ve-detected-that-your-app-is-using-an-old-version-of-the-google-play

Comment: @Jason Yes, I've seen that question. None of the answers there seem related. I have no linked APIs, I'm not hitting any google APIs in my app, I have no serverside component, and I'm not using any billing library.

Comment: Could you please check NuGet packages and Linker option? What packages are you using?

Comment: Based on doc https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/deprecation-faq you can check deps in release build APK Analyzer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Apparently I had `BILLING` permissions set in my manifest.  Removing these fixed the issue.

You can do this by right-clicking the project --> Properties --> Android Manifest --> Searching for `BILLING` under "Required Permissions" and unchecking it

Alternatively, open `AndroidManifest.xml` and delete the line

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

Answer (score 0):

use this in your manifest application tag

```
<service android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.MessageForwardingService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" android:exported="false"></service>
```

and remove this :
permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"

Answer (score 0):

Add the below implementation app/build.gradle file. It solved my problem. The project was build using Flutter.

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:4.0.0'
```

}